# Script not uploading files to my server

Tags: php

This is the code I'm using for my website. You can see the HTML input:

```
<form action="upload_request.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="file"/> 
    <i>Only Excel files (*.xls || *.xlsx)</i>
</form>
```

And here there's the PHP script:

```
<?php    
$uploaddir = '/cdir/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "fail!!\n";
}
?>
```

I have to upload an excel file in my folder `dir` but this script is not doing that and he always "fail!!". Could you help me please?

Comment: Is that linux, the directory have permission to write for all or your user/group have that permission?

Answer (score 6):

Your `<form>` tag should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. See the [example #1 here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).